Future tenses doing something up to a point in time
I want to say that I will be engaged in doing something by some time in the future and maybe even after that deadline. How to do it?

I will be doing it by Monday
Or
2)I will have beein doing it by Monday

Please, explain why something is correct and wrong

I want to start doinv something before Monday and maybe even later. So yours won't work


I'll be busy doing reports UNTIL Monday. 2) I will have finished doing the reports BY Monday evening


@Mari-LouA Does my 1 examples mean that I will be engaged in doing something before and up to Monday and maybe even later? –


It implies the action/task will finish on Monday. If the person suspects they cannot finish the task before Monday they shouldn't give any specific day. But if there's room to wiggle, they can say: "I ought to have finished doing the job before Monday or Tuesday at the very latest.”


@Mari-LouA if that's the meaning of my first example so how is iti dufferent to these 1 I will do it by Monday 2 I will have done it by Monday

In most cases, we wouldn't use a continuous verb form in "I'll do it by Monday". Sometimes it makes sense to say something like "I''ll be driving a new car by Monday" (for activities that normally take a long time, or don't relate to "completed acts"). It's not so easy to think of contexts where the Perfect form "I'll have been driving a new car by Monday" would make sense - you'd normally need to explicitly specify how long the "past in the future" activity had been ongoing, as in "I'll have been driving a new car for three days by Monday" (and it still might sound "odd").

@FumbleFingers If I said " I will have driven a new car by Monday" it would mean that I'll stop doing it later , so wrong in this context. " I will drive a new car by Monday" would mean the same as 'will be driving", correct?

Your first comment I want to start doing something before Monday and maybe even later doesn't make sense. I assume what you wanted to say was something like I want to start doing something before Monday but I may continue doing it after Monday. But that's not really enough to establish exactly what you're trying to say. Much depends on whether what you will be doing is a "goal-oriented" task (with a clear way of indicating that it's done, finished), OR some kind of activity that once you've started, you might continue to do indefinitely, like feeling happy.

@FumbleFingers 1 I will finish by Monday 2 I will have finished by Monday 3 I will be finishing by Monday. Are all three fine with the same meaning that something will be finished on or beforw Monday?

Your #1 and #2 would normally mean the same, but #2 is "marked" because we don't usually use more complex verb forms than necessary. If you (as a non-native speaker) said #2 to me, I'd probably take it for granted you meant #1 (the job will definitely be completed before you finish work on Monday, but I may have already finished in on Friday or earlier). If I knew it came from a competent carefully-spoken native Anglophone, I'd assume he meant the job will be finished by = before Monday (so if I need to use it first thing Monday morning it will be ready for me).

...I won't bother going into what I'd make of your #3 there, because 99% of the time it would just be a non-native speaker unfamiliar with idiomatic English. It's remotely feasible a careful competent speaker might say it, but I don;t think I'd be doing you any favours by trying to contrive a possible context. You have nothing to gain from this random jumbling up of tenses. Learn the natural ways to say the things you need to say, and forget about all these "syntactically valid, but unlikely" permutations.

It becomes difficult to explain the reasoning for all the grammar modifications, but I think the following wording should be fine.  Let's switch "doing" to "working" or another verb, for aesthetic reasons.  "I'll have (at least) started working on that by Monday."

Expressing possibility by using modal verbs - may, might.
If my understanding is correct, OP want to suggest that he might not complete the assigned task by the deadline.
To express this, one should use the appropriate modal verb as explained below
Ref Adventures with Grammar and Composition, Beena Sugatham. Oxford Printing Press

We can also use may or might to show probability or possibility. May indicates a good possibility and might, a weak possibility though there is very little difference. We have already seen how could suggests possibility. It expresses still weaker possibility than might


Must and will can also be used to indicate certainty or likelihood. Must expresses a logical certainty and is used in a context stronger than may. As Sherlock Holmes says, 'When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."


Will is used when we are one hundred per cent sure.

Now looking at OP's sentences:


I will be doing it by Monday Or




I will have beein doing it by Monday


We could convey this in simple language as future perfect continuous tense is complicated.
I might (may) finish (complete) the work by Monday.
Future perfect continuous tense
Ref. LSI education website
https://www.lsi.edu/en/future-perfect-continuous-tense

We use the preposition by to express a point in the future (either a time or an action) that allows us to measure the duration of the activity. Usually the by phrase comes first, followed by a comma. Then the independent clause includes the future perfect continuous. The duration of the activity is usually expressed as for + duration of time.

Applying this to communicate what Op want to say

I want to say that I will be engaged in doing something by some time in the future and maybe even after that deadline. How to do it?

By next Monday when I might finish the project, I will have been working on it for three months.

I modified my answer because I felt OP wanted to use the future tense.
