Expressing duration
I want to express that up to some point in time I will be engaged in doing something for some time.
1I will be doing it for 20 years by Monday
Or
2 I will have been doing it for 20 years by Monday
I think only 2 is good. I think if we changed "by Monday" to "Before I die" then both would be fine. Am I right twice?

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-continuous-i-will-be-working and

Can you give an example of this action in the progressive state. Can you come up with an action that is ongoing or repeated for twenty years, instead of  saying "doing it"? The questions are getting really boring, and they all beginning to sound the same.

You already asked this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353179/future-tenses-doing-something-up-to-a-point-in-time

Does this answer your question? Future tenses doing something up to a point in time

"I will be asking questions on ELL for 6 days by Monday" is not idiomatically likely, but I'd say it's syntactically acceptable. If not with those specific actions and times, I imagine it's possible to contrive a context where that construction might be the preferred phrasing. But as @Mari-LouA says, the questions are getting really boring - often more about lateral thinking for contrived contexts, rather than learning English.

1 I will do it next month. 2 I will have done it next month.  Does 1 mean during next month and 2 before next? If not correct me please

@Lambie . What do you think

@FumbleFingers and you?

Maybe I need to add "by" before next week?

Changing it to before I die doesn't improve anything. How do you know that you won't die before the twenty years are up?

@KateBunting  ok thanks. What about my question here which you can see in the comments

(1) yes, and (2) 'I will have done it by next month' is more idiomatic, and probably means 'by the beginning of next month'.

"By" is only idiomatic for something that could be completed in advance. Because you can't complete an anniversary beforehand, "doing it for 20 years by next Monday" is not at all idiomatic. "I'll have been doing it for 20 years next Monday" is okay.

As I said in your other question: will have been [action verb] is best used with a time period. Oh boy, by next week, I will have been skiing on black slopes for 0 years.

We can project how long something will be ongoing:

She will be working for 15 more years before she can begin to collect social security.

or we can time-travel into the future, so to speak, and look back retrospectively at what had been ongoing between the present, the starting point of our time-traveling journey, and that future point in time, its destination:

She will have been working for 15 more years by the time she starts collecting social security.

In the future perfect version, we are assuming a second reference point in the future (the time she starts collecting social security), and imagining that the time  between the present and that future point has passed, and that she had worked during all that time.

1"I will have been doing it for 20 years by Monday"
I'd like to paraphrase sentence number 1. I have my own versions. Can you check if they will do?
2I will be doing it for 20 years by Monday
3I will do it for 20 years by Monday

Sorry, that would be proofreading.

why? I just want to know if there are valid options to substidute my original sentence with

"for 20 years by Monday" is not ideal since "by Monday" can mean "not later than Monday".   You need a definite time point construction for your sentence.  Like "as of Monday" or "come Monday".
