Paraphrasing sentences

I will have been doing it for 20 years by Monday

I'd like to paraphrase sentence number 1. I have my own versions. Can you check if they will do?

I will be doing it for 20 years by Monday
I will do it for 20 years by Monday


Changing verb tenses changes meaning. The original sentence is so simple that there isn't room for much change. (And no, these examples don't work.)

@AndyBonner  How would you understand my 2 and 3 then?

They're just not combinations of words that make sense. Using future tense with a duration, like "I will do it for [this amount of time]" means you're about to start that time span. And when we use a day of the week with no other explanation, we mean "next Monday," which is not 20 years away.

@Lambie Sorry for that my logic is quite f@cked up but I'm getting to it. Thanks to you

I am confident that by next month, you will have been using this for about 20 days.

Sentence #1 does not work.  There is little value in paraphrasing a sentence that doesn't work to begin with.  You can structure that sentence to read, I will have been doing it for 20 years on Monday.  I can't see any way to paraphrase that short sentence.

The spelling is "paraphrase", as in to re-work the "phrase".
Your paraphrased examples do not work due to the incorrect tense in the first verb. You can rephrase the rest of the sentence, however, to discuss an action that you have been performing for a given time, you need the present perfect.
The sentence could be paraphrased without changing the meaning as, for example,

I will have been doing this for exactly 20 years on Monday.
On Monday, I will have been doing this for 20 years.
I have been doing this for almost two decades; it will (be/have been) 20 years on Monday.

...however, you are stuck with "have been" for the first verb tense.
Your examples are:

I will be doing it for 20 years by Monday.

This is incorrect, however, if someone spoke the above to me, I would understand what they meant. The future tense is being used to describe past actions: you can't use "will be doing" to refer to actions in the past. To move these actions into the past, you must add "have" as in "will have been doing".

I will do it for 20 years by Monday.

This is even more incorrect, and I wouldn't immediately understand what the speaker meant--it would take some time for my brain to correct the grammar here. "I will do it for 20 years" implies that you are going to spend twenty years performing the action. Adding "by Monday" to the end confuses the meaning as you've now specified two incompatible timeframes to the verb, "20 years" and "by Monday". It sounds like you are going to bend time and space to fit twenty years in before next Monday.
EDIT:

I will do it for 2 days by Monday.
I will be doing it for 2 days by Monday.

Both of these are incorrect. Because the timeframe is "by Monday", you are still discussing something that you will have been doing for two days. To get rid of the future perfect, you would need to modify the sentences to get rid of the timeframe:

I am going to do it for two days.
I will do it for two days.

To maintain the timeframe, you would need to say something like:

I am going to do it for two days, from today to Monday.
I'll do it, starting today and finishing on Monday.
I'm going to do it until Monday.

As long as the timeframe is "by Monday", you need "have" somewhere.

"What if I mean something that I'm gonna start now and I haven't done before?" In that case, "I will do it for 20 years" is technically correct, although "I'll spend 20 years doing it" sounds more natural.

Check these examples here 1 I will do it for 2 days By Monday 2 I will be doing it for 2 days by Monday. Let's say I'm gonna start it now and today is friday. In this situation 1 and 2 are correct ancI don't need future perfect, correct?

see edits to my answer

is it all about prepositions? Let's change "by" 1 I will do/be doing it for two days BEFORE Monday. 2 I will do/be doing it for  until Monday. Are now my examples correct and perfect is just optional here?

Not necessarily, for example, you could say "I will get this done by Monday" without needing a perfect tense (but "I will have/will have gotten this done by Monday" also works). Your example "I will do/be doing it until Monday" does work, but not "I will do/be doing it for until Monday." I'm not sure if "for until" was a typo but you can't use these together like that.

"I will do/be doing it for two days before Monday" doesn't work either, the timeframe is still the same, in this case "before Monday" and "by Monday" are effectively the same--that is, you're referencing a point in the future by which time the action will have been completed.

Does it work the same way in the past? 1 I had been doing it for two days by Monday . Not I did it for two days by Monday?

Yes. I had been doing it for two days by Monday is correct, whereas I did it for two days by Monday is incorrect. I had done it for two days by Monday is also correct.

Does it change anything if instead of "for" I use "in"? What about I will do/be doing in two days by Monday. Is perfect then possible too

Can you specify which sentence you mean?

I did now ncncn

I forgot about "it" sorry

The meaning changes entirely. "I will do it in two days by Monday" implies that you're going to complete the task by Monday, and you'll do it in two days at some point in the future. It's a wonky sentence that sounds a bit like bragging: it'll only take me two days where it would take most other people four or five. I'll have it done by Monday. "I will be doing it in two days by Monday" implies that the speaker has been repetitively performing an activity and, by Monday, they expect their time to perform this activity will be down to two days.

Thank you so much. Does it make any sense to say " I will have done it in 2 days by Monday?

That has the same meaning as "I will be doing it in two days by Monday." but "will have done" shows more confidence that you'll have the time to complete the task down to two days.

Can you think of any prepositions with which perfect isn't needed for instance "I will be doing it for two hours when you come" would be I think ok. So we have one "when". Can you give me more. Before, I asked a different question and a guy answered using future continuous wirth before and not perfect Can you explain why? Here's the link https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353194/expressing-duration/353211?noredirect=1#comment693504_353211

"I will be doing it for two hours when you come" is coherent but "I will have been doing it for two hours when you come" is correct. Not sure about the rest, that seems like a separate question.

That person wrote "She will be working for 15 more years before she can begin to collect social security." Why is it correct? Don't we need perfect before "before"?

Both are coherent, but "She will have been working..." sounds better to me.

Yeah, but does coherent mean correct? I think you told me before to use perfect with before

Correct is relative to the context. Is this speech between peers? I would not think twice about the grammar if someone spoke either sentence to me, the meaning is perfectly clear. If this for an exam being graded for perfect grammar, however, I might take a point off for "She will be working for 15 more years" versus "she will have been working".

What about " I was doing it for 2 hours before she came" understandable but perfect grammar requires "perfect"?

That's correct.

On the other hand, "I was a small business owner for 20 years before the big box stores came along" is correct but here we don't have a progressive verb form like doing/going/being. "I had been a small business owner..." is also correct.

I really do want to thank you. You answered so many of my questions. That's just wonderful. Thank you once again.

But saying "I will have been doing it in two days by Monday is wrong, right? To make it correct we need to change "in" to "for", correct?

Like I said above, "I will have been doing it in two days by Monday" isn't incorrect, it just has a different meaning. It implies you've been doing some long term repetitive task and, by Monday, you'll have gotten the time to complete that task down to two days.

It means I have been doing it before Monday amd once Monday starts I will have two days to finish it. Do I get it right?

No, it means that I was doing it before Monday and I was given two days time to finish it up to Monday. Now correct?

No. when you say "in two days", it sounds like "I've been working on my jigsaw puzzle skills by doing at least two puzzles per week. When I started, it took me three or four days to finish a puzzle, however, I will have been doing it in two days by Monday."

Note that even the above sentence is extremely awkward and better phrased as "...however, I'm now doing it in two days." as referencing Monday seems arbitrary given the context.

Yeak it's akward even I feel it and abviously I'm not a native. But is there a diffferenve between 1 I will be doing it in two days by Monday and I will have been doing it in two days by Monday?

No, no difference.

Can I say something like that? 1 I will be driving by Friday 2 I was swimming by Friday. If continuous without duration stated doesn't go well with "by". Please tell me why and please say if you know any exception?

What do you think?

I think you should gather your thoughts together, and post one question with examples that covers all your problems so we don't need to go back and forth like this. This type of exchange may be helpful for you, but anyone else with similar questions who comes upon this page isn't going to want to wade through 50 comments to find their answer.

even though saying "I will have been doing it in 2 days by Monda" is akward it makes sense but saying for instance " I will have been doing it in 2 days next week or on monday" would be wrong. Here I have to use future continuous. Right?
